# The signs of q-coefficients of completely replicable functions

Tags: rt.representation-theory

McKay, Strauss, Communications in Algebra, 18, pp.253-278. (1990) displays data
suggesting that, replacing the q-coefficients by their signs in {0,+1,-1}, 
produces an ultimately periodic series with period dividing the modular level. 
Can the periodic sign sequence be nicely described?  A similar table is in Ford,
McKay, Norton Communications in Algebra 22, pp.5175 - 5193 (1994).

Comment: Could you please reproduce here the data, so that everybody can have a look at it ?

Comment: Please answer here rather than by mail, so that everybody can learn something. You told me that the tables are too large for mathoverflow. Please think of those like me that do not have access to the journal. See http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1037906 and http://tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927879008823911

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer** (I know this is an old question.  But I have become interested in this recently.)

To find the data, see this listing at OEIS: [Index entries for McKay-Thompson series for Monster simple group](https://oeis.org/index/Mat#McKay_Thompson).  (Do I remember correctly that there are 171 of these completely replicable sequences?  Despite the OEIS titles, not all of them are monstrous.)  But note that some sequences that would naturally have 0's in all even spots: those zeros are omitted in the OEIS listing.  You can look in the "EXAMPLES" section for something like "T5B = " to see whether this is the case.

Has there been progress on this question?